# ArcMap drawing 0-values in raster as blank

Tags: arcmap, symbology, rendering, nodata, map-drawing

I am visualizing a series of rasters with floating point data ranging from -30 to +50. In ArcMap 10.7, I am using a Classified color scheme for symbology that bins the values into 10's. At my desired zoom level, raster values of 0 are appearing as blank (no color, circled in red), even though 0 is a data value. When I zoom in really far, the 0 value draws in the appropriate color (orange). Is there any way to make sure 0 draws at all zoom levels?

Zoomed in map:

[image: Map zoomed in. Orange area with 0 value draws.]

Zoomed out map:

[image: Map zoomed out. Area with 0 value does not draw (circled in red).]
[image: Symbology legend]

Comment: Most probably it is a corrupted pyramid level. I suggest [re-building the pyramids](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-pyramids.htm) by Skip Existing option unchecked.

Comment: Thank you, fatih_dur, that solved it!